# How to access Settings array for Woocommerce plugins?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

So I've been having a lot of trouble developing plugins for Woocommerce. Idk if I suck at reading documentation or just that barely any exists.

How do I actually access the values in this settings array?

```
            $settings[] = array(
                "name" => __("Virtual Products Only", "autocomplete-orders"),
                "id" => "aco_vpo",
                "type" => "checkbox",
                "desc" => __("", "autocomplete-orders"),
                "css" => "",
                "default" => "",
                "desc_tip" => __("", "autocomplete-orders"),
            );
```

The file with the code above is required by my main php plugin file like this

```
require ACO_PATH . "/incl/woo-settings/autocomplete-orders.php";
```

How do I actually pull the values from the settings array to be used in my main.php?

For further information, here is the full code of the settings file I generated with a tool

```
<?php

/**
 * @author Kaleb Smith
 * @package AutocompleteOrdersWooSetting
 * @license GNU General Public License v2 or later
**/


defined("ACO_EXEC") or die("Silent is golden");

class AutocompleteOrdersWooSetting{
    
    
    /**
     * AutocompleteOrdersWooSetting:__construct()
    **/
    function __construct(){
        add_filter("woocommerce_get_sections_checkout", array($this, "AcoAutocompleteOrdersaddSection"));
        add_filter("woocommerce_get_settings_checkout", array($this, "AcoAutocompleteOrdersSetting"), 10, 2);
    }
    
    
    /**
     * AutocompleteOrdersWooSetting:AcoAutocompleteOrdersaddSection()
    **/
    function AcoAutocompleteOrdersaddSection($sections){
        $sections["aco_autocomplete_orders"] = __("Autocomplete Orders", "autocomplete-orders");
        return $sections;
    }
    
    
    /**
     * AutocompleteOrdersWooSetting:AcoAutocompleteOrdersSetting()
    **/
    function AcoAutocompleteOrdersSetting($settings, $current_section){
        if ($current_section == "aco_autocomplete_orders"){
            $settings = array();
            $settings[] = array("type" => "title", "name" => __("Autocomplete Orders","autocomplete-orders"), "desc" => __("", "autocomplete-orders" ), "id" => "aco_autocomplete_orders" );
                // TODO: CUSTOM-CODE --|-- options
        
            
            // vpo
            $settings[] = array(
                "name" => __("Virtual Products Only", "autocomplete-orders"),
                "id" => "aco_vpo",
                "type" => "checkbox",
                "desc" => __("", "autocomplete-orders"),
                "css" => "",
                "default" => "",
                "desc_tip" => __("", "autocomplete-orders"),
            );
            
            $wc_gateways      = new WC_Payment_Gateways();
            $payment_gateways = $wc_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways();

            foreach ($payment_gateways as $gateway){
                $title = $gateway->get_title();
                // ofpm
                $settings[] = array(
                    "name" => __("Turn on for {$title}", "autocomplete-orders"),
                    "id" => "aco_{$title}",
                    "type" => "checkbox",
                    "desc" => __("", "autocomplete-orders"),
                    "css" => "",
                    "default" => "",
                    "desc_tip" => __("", "autocomplete-orders"),
                );
            }
            
            // exsku
            $settings[] = array(
                "name" => __("Turn off based on exploded sku", "autocomplete-orders"),
                "desc_tip" => __("eg product-5454 exploded by - would become product. This option is helpful for filtering by SKU", "autocomplete-orders"),
                "id" => "aco_exsku",
                "type" => "text",
                "desc" => __("kinguin-2354 to kinguin", "autocomplete-orders"),
                "default" => "",
                "css" => "",
            );
            
            
            // processing
            
            $options = array(
                "completed " => __("Completed ","autocomplete-orders"),
                " processing " => __(" Processing ","autocomplete-orders"),
                " pending payment " => __(" Pending Payment ","autocomplete-orders"),
                " cancelled " => __(" Cancelled ","autocomplete-orders"),
                " on hold" => __(" On Hold","autocomplete-orders"),
            );
            $settings[] = array(
                "name" => __("change Processing to", "autocomplete-orders"),
                "desc_tip" => __("", "autocomplete-orders"),
                "id" => "aco_processing",
                "type" => "select",
                "css" => "",
                "default" => "",
                "options" => $options,
            );
            
            
            // on-hold
            
            $options = array(
                "completed " => __("Completed ","autocomplete-orders"),
                " processing " => __(" Processing ","autocomplete-orders"),
                " pending payment " => __(" Pending Payment ","autocomplete-orders"),
                " cancelled " => __(" Cancelled ","autocomplete-orders"),
                " on hold" => __(" On Hold","autocomplete-orders"),
            );
            $settings[] = array(
                "name" => __("change On Hold to", "autocomplete-orders"),
                "desc_tip" => __("", "autocomplete-orders"),
                "id" => "aco_on_hold",
                "type" => "select",
                "css" => "",
                "default" => "",
                "options" => $options,
            );
            
                
            $settings[] = array("type" => "sectionend", "id" => "aco_autocomplete_orders");
            return $settings;
        }else{
            return $settings;
        }
    }
    
    
}
//EOF
```

To me it looks like the array is just being overwritten here? Makes no sense to me.

Can anyone provide clarity on what this code is actually doing?

Added settings that show successfully.

No idea on how to utilize these settings in main script.

Answer (score 0):

To access the values in the settings array defined in your WooCommerce plugin, you can use the '**get_option**' function provided by WordPress. In your '**main.php**' file, where you need to retrieve these values, you can use '**get_option**' with the appropriate option name, which in this case is the '**"id"**' specified in your settings array.

For example, if you want to retrieve the value for "Virtual Products Only" setting, you would use:

```
$virtual_products_only = get_option('aco_vpo');
```

This will fetch the value of "Virtual Products Only" from the WordPress options table. Repeat this for each setting you want to access. The '**'id'**' field in the settings array is the key to use when retrieving the settings.

Make sure you use the correct '**'id'**' for each setting you want to retrieve.